# Where are Champernowne's zeroes?

Tags: code-golf, string, integer, decision-problem

Consider the infinite string of all nonnegative decimal integers concatenated together in order (akin to [Champernowne's constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant)):

```
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930...979899100101102103...
```

Write a program or function that takes in a nonnegative integer that indexes (0-based) into this infinite string. Output a [truthy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/26997) value if the digit indexed is 0, otherwise output a [falsy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/26997) value if the digit is 1-9.

The shortest code in bytes wins.

The first 25 truthy-producing inputs are:

```
0
11
31
51
71
91
111
131
151
171
191
192
194
197
200
203
206
209
212
215
218
222
252
282
312
```

Kudos if your program is memory effecient, but this is not a requirement.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A031287

Comment: is it not better that program or that function return the digit of that array from its index [not only if that is 0 or not]?

Comment: Related: [Row of natural numbers](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54276/12012)

Comment: I can't understand what this question is asking at all lol can someone explain it

Comment: Can we return an infinite sequence of truthy indices?

Answer (score 12):

### Haskell, 25 bytes

```
(<'1').((show=<<[0..])!!)
```

Usage example: `(<'1').((show=<<[0..])!!)  312` -> `True`

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

Code:

```
ÝJ¹è_
```

Explanation:

```
Ý      # Get the list [0 .. input].
 J     # Join the list.
  ¹    # Get the first input again.
   è   # Get the character on that index.
    _  # Logical negate (0 -> 1, everything else -> 0).
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w51KwrnDqF8&input=MjE4)

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, <s>42</s> 40 bytes

```
(0@@Join@@IntegerDigits@Range@#)[[#]]<1&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a number as input and returns either `True` or `False` as output. A longer, yet more efficient(?) solution:

```
RealDigits[ChampernowneNumber[],10,1,-#][[1,1]]<1&
```

Answer (score 5):

### CJam, 9 bytes

```
{_),s=~!}
```

This is an unnamed block (function) which takes in an integer and returns 0 or 1 accordingly.

Explanation:

```
{       }        Defines a block
 _               Copy input n
  ),             Increment n and take range
    s            Convert to string - for a list of numbers this concatenates
                 the digits
     =           Index, getting nth digit
      ~          Evaluate the digit character into a number
       !         Logical negation
```

[Online interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=11%20%7B_%29%2Cs%3D~!%7D%20~). Note that `~` evaluates a block. Alternative, you can run this [test suite](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=1000%20%7B_%29%2Cs%3D~!%7D%2C%20p) which uses `,` to filter the first 1000 numbers for truthy values.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
RDF⁸ị¬
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UkRG4oG44buLwqw&input=&args=MTEx) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UkRG4oG44buLwqwKMzEz4bi2w4fDkGY&input=).

#### How it works

```
RDF⁸ị¬  Main link. Argument: n

R       Range; yield [1, ..., n].
 D      Decimal; convert all integers in that range to base 10 arrays.
  F     Flatten the result.
   ⁸ị   Extract the digit at index n (1-based).
        This returns 0 if the array is empty (n = 0).
     ¬  Logical NOT; return 1 if the digit is 0, 0 if not.
```

Answer (score 4):

## MATL, 11 bytes

```
Qt:qVXzw)U~
```

[**Try it Online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=UXQ6cVZYencpVX4&input=MTE)

**Explanation**:

```
    % Implicitly grab input as an integer (N)
Qt  % Add 1 and duplicate
:q  % Create an array from [0 ... N]
V   % Convert each entry to a string (places spaces between each number)
Xz  % Remove all whitespace
w)  % Get the N+1 element of the string (since MATL uses 1-based indexing natively)
U~  % Convert the result back to a number and negate which yields TRUE if it was '0' and
    % FALSE otherwise
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

**2 bytes thanks to Fatalize.**

```
y@ec:?m0
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=eUBlYzo_bTA&input=MzEy)

```
y@ec:?m0

y         range from 0 to Input, inclusive,
 @e       the digits of every number in that range,
   c      concatenated
    :?m   the Input-th digit
       0  is zero.
```

Comment: `@e` vectorizes so `y@ec:?m0` works, to save 2 bytes.

Comment: @Fatalize How many other operators vectorize?

Comment: Only `#0`, `#1`, `#+`, `#_`, `#>` and `#<` vectorize like `@e` does. Some of the predicates that vectorize such as `+` or `*` don't vectorize recursively to the lowest list level, and don't perform the same thing depending on the structure of the input.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
{!+map(|*.comb,0..*)[$_]}
```

A lambda that takes a number as input and returns a `True` or `False`.

Memory-efficient.

**How it works**

1. `0..*` – Construct the range from 0 to infinity.
2. `map(|*.comb,  )` – Lazily iterate the range, replacing each number with the characters of its string representation, and returning a new lazy sequence. The `|` keeps the new sequence flattened.
3. `[$_]` – Take the element at the index defined by the (implicitly declared) lambda parameter `$_`.
4. `+` – Coerce it to a number. *(This step is needed because coercing a string directly to a boolean always gives True unless the string is empty.)*
5. `!` – Coerce it to a boolean and negate it.

([try it online](https://glot.io/snippets/ehx8swz0lk))

*EDIT: -1 byte thanks to b2gills.*

Comment: You can shorten yours to `{!+map(|*.comb,0..*)[$_]}` I came up with `{!+({|($++).comb}...*)[$_]}` before looking to see if there was already a P6 answer. `!+` can be replaced by `1>`

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3.5, 40 bytes

```python
lambda n:('%d'*-~n%(*range(n),n))[n]<'1'
```

Test it on [repl.it](https://repl.it/CxxI).

#### How it works

For input **n**, `'%d'*-~n` repeats the format string **n + 1** times.

`(*range(n),n)` unpacks the range **[0, ..., n - 1]** and yields the tuple **(0, ..., n)**.

`...%...` replaces each occurrence of **%d** with the corresponding integer in the range, yielding the string **01234567891011...n**.

`(...)[n]<'1'` selects the character at index **n** and tests if it is less than the character **1**.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 44 bytes

```
lambda n:''.join(map(str,range(n+1)))[n]<'1'
```

An anonymous function that takes input via argument and returns `True` or `False` as appropriate.

**How it works**

```
lambda n      Anonymous function with input n
range(n+1)    Yield the range [0, n]...
map(str,...)  ...convert all elements to string...
''.join(..)   ...concatenate...
...[n]        ...yield nth character...
:...<'1'      ...return True if int(character)==0 else return False
```

[Try it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/YqPZNg)

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

*Thanks to @LeakyNun for -1 byte*

```
!s@jkUh
```

This is my first attempt at golfing in Pyth.

A full program that prints `True` or `False` as appropriate.

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%21s%40jkUh&debug=0)

[First 25 truthy inputs](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=FNr0+313I%21s%40jkUhNNN&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11&debug=0)

**How it works**

```
!s@jkUh    Program. Input: Q
      hQ   Head. Yield Q+1
     U     Unary range. Yield [0, Q]
   jk      Join. Join on empty string
  @     Q  Index. Yield string[Q]
 s         Integer. Convert to integer
!          Logical negation. 0 -> True, all other digits -> False
           Print. Print result implicitly
```

Answer (score 3):

## [S.I.L.O.S](http://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 141 bytes

```
readIO
i+1
lblL
c=C
p=1
lblc
p*10
c/10
if c c
p/10
lbln
m=C
m/p
m%10
p/10
i-1
if i C
GOTO H
lblC
if p n
C+1
GOTO L
lblH
m/m
m-1
m|
printInt m
```

[Try it online!](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=cmVhZElPCmkrMQpsYmxMCmM9QwpwPTEKbGJsYwpwKjEwCmMvMTAKaWYgYyBjCnAvMTAKbGJsbgptPUMKbS9wCm0lMTAKcC8xMAppLTEKaWYgaSBDCkdPVE8gSApsYmxDCmlmIHAgbgpDKzEKR09UTyBMCmxibEgKbS9tCm0tMQptfApwcmludEludCBt&input=&args=MzEy)

Uses only 5 integers, maximum memory efficiency \o/

#### Explanation

We generate as many digits as the input in the Champernowne's constant.

In the main loop, we do the following:

- Find the length of the current number by floor_dividing it by 10 repeatedly until it reaches 0, and then count the number of divisions used.
- Instead of storing the number of divisions, we store 10 to that number power instead.
- Iterate through each digit as such: the `100`s digit of `1234` is obtained by `(1234/10)%10` where `/` is floor division.
- For each digit generated, take 1 from the input, while checking if the input reached zero.
- If the input reaches zero, check if the current digit is 0 and then halts.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 45 bytes + Kudos

```
f=(n,s='0')=>s[n]?!+s[n]:f(n-s.length,-~s+'')
```

My best non-Kudos version was 34 bytes:

```
n=>!+(g=s=>s[n]||g(s+i++))('',i=0)
```

Comment: I thought kudos was a library until I realized there was a kudos on the challenge :P

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 47 bytes

`n=>[...Array(n+1)].reduce((a,_,i)=>a+i,'')[n]<1`

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>42</s> 33 bytes

```
n=>!+(r=i=>i>n?'':i+r(i+1))(0)[n]
```

Example:

```js
let f =
n=>!+(r=i=>i>n?'':i+r(i+1))(0)[n]

// test all integers in [0, 312]
for(var n = 0, list = []; n <= 312; n++) {
  f(n) && list.push(n);
}
console.log(list.join(','));
```

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 56 bytes

```
def f(n){def s=''<<'';(0..n).each{s<<it};!(s[n] as int)}
```

Nothing fancy, but I'm trying out some new things.

```
def f(n) {
  def s = ''<<''           // declare a StringBuffer
  (0..n).each { s << it }
  !(s[n] as int)           // Groovy considers a non-null char truthy, so we have to cast 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 24  bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Run with input on STDIN:

```
zero.pl <<< 31
```

print 1 for zero, nothing otherwise

`zero.pl`

```
$_=!(map/./g,0..$_)[$_]
```

Answer (score 1):

## zsh, 31 bytes

```
exit ${${(j..):-{0..$1}}[$1+1]}
```

`exit 0` is true in zsh

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>35</s> 23 bytes

This is an anonymous function that concatenates `[0..n]`, takes the `n`th index and checks if that char is `"0"` (less than `"1"`). Golfing suggestions welcome.

```ruby
->n{([*0..n]*'')[n]<?1}
```

**Ungolfing**

```ruby
->n{...}   # Create an anonymous function with parameter n.
[*0..n]    # Create an array of the range [0..n].
[...]*''   # Join the array using the empty string.
(...)[n]   # Take the char at the n-th index of the string.
<?1        # Check if the char is < "1" (that is, "0").
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 36 bytes

```
<?=!join(range(0,$a=$argv[1]))[$a];
```

Print `1` if Champernowne argument-th decimal is `0`, else print '' (empty string).

Answer (score 1):

## R, <strike>61</strike> 57 bytes

Thanks to @plannapus for 4 bytes.

```
n=scan();strsplit(paste(0:n,collapse=""),"")[[1]][n+1]==0
```

Creates a vector of numbers 0:n (for 0 indexing), creates a string of them, pulls the nth value from string (adjusting for 0 indexing). Converts to numeric and tests if it is 0.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, <s>31</s> 28 bytes

```bash
seq -s "" 0 $1|egrep ^.{$1}0
```

Output is non-empty (truthy) or empty (falsy). Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/7MOc2A).

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```julia
!n=join(0:n)[n+1]<49
```

*Thanks to @LuisMendo for golfing off 1 byte!*

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=IW49am9pbigwOm4pW24rMV08NDkKCmZvciBuIGluIDA6MzEyCiAgICBpZiAhbiBwcmludGxuKG4pIGVuZAplbmQ&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each/9429#9429)

```apl
{~×⍎⍵⊃∊⍕¨⍳1+⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc49CsJAEAXgPqdIL0Jm15ikFsRUguYCAVGLgOJPEUSbQJDAihbByt7OQryA3mQuEndeivlg5z3YSddZd5an2WrR8KWOx1xeveZw@t3ZXNh8uCr4XLGpv082b@rY1bGZ25LE6FfF96W5vNnXdDKwJqN42rB5uMM02@bO3CU7yo6WIYLacaSSbPa7pXQ86bWRxRcCISIEEBEhI4TUppGCPRjIZ54HNezDSCQFfRiKChsfhjiS1B8)

### Explanation

```apl
{~×⍎⍵⊃∊⍕¨⍳1+⍵}     ⍝ 
{            }     ⍝ A dfn, in this case with a single argument (⍵)
         ⍳1+⍵      ⍝ Computes the range of 0..arg
       ⍕¨          ⍝ For each (¨), convert to a string (⍕)
      ∊            ⍝ Enlist all strings into a single string
    ⍵⊃             ⍝ Pick (⊃) the element at the index of the given arg (⍵)
   ⍎               ⍝ 'Execute' to treat it as a numeric
  ×                ⍝ Turn >1 into 1
 ~                 ⍝ Negate
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 38 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.75 bytes

```
ʀṅi0=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwiyoDhuYVpMD0iLCIiLCIzMiJd)

Answer (score 0):

## GolfScript, 12 bytes

```
~.),""*\=48=
```

Explanation:

```
~             Evaluate the input.
 .            Duplicate it
  )           Increment the duplicate.
   ,          Create an array from 0 to it.
    ""*       Join it with an empty string.
       \=     Get the n-th index of this string, where n is the input
         48=  Is it equal to 0?
```

[Try it online](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=fi4pLCIiKlw9NDg9&input=MTEx) or [verify all test cases!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=bi97fi4pLCIiKlw9NDg9fVwlbio&input=MAoxMQozMQo1MQo3MQo5MQoxMTEKMTMxCjE1MQoxNzEKMTkxCjE5MgoxOTQKMTk3CjIwMAoyMDMKMjA2CjIwOQoyMTIKMjE1CjIxOAoyMjIKMjUyCjI4MgozMTI)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (ES5): <strike>61</strike> 60 bytes

```
function(b){for(s="";s.length<b;)s+=s.length;return 0==s[b]}
```

Ungolfed:

```
function a(b){
  for(var s="";s.length<b;)
    s+=s.length;
  }
  return (s[b]==0);
}
```

Old:

```
function(n){s="";while(s.length<n)s+=s.length;return s[n]==0}
```

Ungolfed old:

```
function a(n){
  var str="";
  while(str.length<n)str+=str.length; //Create String as long as needed
  return str[n]==0 //Check for 0 and return
}
```

Comment: How about `!s[n]` instead of `s[n]==0`?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Does not work for me. My function a returns a(31)=true, while yours (`function(n){s="";while(s.length<n)s+=s.length;return !s[n]}`) returns a(31)=false.

Comment: hm. my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**C, 154 bytes**

```
s(n,v,k,z){for(k=1;(z=n%10,n/=10)&&!v||k<v;++k); return v?z:k;}
f(n,i,j,c){for(i=0,j=0;;++i){c=s(i,0,0,0);j+=c;if(j>n){c=s(i,j-n,c,0);break;}}return !c;}
```

the function that calculate the value is f(n,0,0,0) where n is the input index.
it can calculate from index changing "return !c" in "return c" the value of the array in that index... 
i don't understand how but it seems to work ok....

```
main()
{int   i,r;
 char  a[]="0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536";

 for(i=0; i<1000; ++i) 
    if(r=f(i,0,0,0))  
        printf("%u|",i);
}
/*
 154
 0|11|31|51|71|91|111|131|151|171|191|192|194|197|200|203|206|209|212|215|218|222
|252|282|312|342|372|402|432|462|491|492|494|497|500|503|506|509|512|515|518|522|552
|582|612|642|672|702|732|762|791|792|794|797|800|803|806|809|812|815|818|822|852
|882|912|942|972|
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

## CoffeeScript, 56 bytes

```
a=(b)->
 s=""
 while s.length<b #loop for building string with required length
  s+=s.length     #add number
 "0"==s[b]        #return, if the number at the position equals zero
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 71 bytes

And I thought it was short at first, but then I had to add `n+=11` to prevent it from throwing a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` when numbers below 11 were input

```
return String.Join("",Enumerable.Range(0,n+=11).ToArray())[n]=='0'?1:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 7 bytes

```
m`sQ@b!
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=m%60sQ%40b%21&input=12)

Answer (score 0):

## Actually, <s>9</s> 8 bytes

This answer concatenates the range `[0..n]`, takes the `n`th index and checks if that char is `"0"`. Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=O3VyzrVqReKJiFk&input=MTE)

```
;urεjE≈Y
```

**Ungolfing**

```
;          Duplicate n
 ur        Increment the duplicate and create range [0..n].
   εj      Join the range with an empty string. Stack: <string> n
     E     Take the char at the n-th index.
      ≈    int(a)
       Y   Logical NOT. If the digit is 0, then return 1, else return 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell v2+, 32 bytes

```
param($n)(-join(0..$n))[$n]-eq48
```

Does the same as other answers -- takes the range from `0` to input `$n`, `-join`s together into a string, takes the `[$n]` index, checks if it's `-eq`ual to `48` (i.e., ASCII for `0`).

Note this will only work up to input `49999`, as the PowerShell range operator `..` only supports ranges of 50,000 elements or fewer. For larger inputs, you'll need to use the following, based on my [previous Champernowne answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66884/42963), at **58 bytes**:

```
param($n)$j=$n;for($c='';$j-ge0;$j--){$c+=$i++}$c[$n]-eq48
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>41</s> 29 bytes

*Credit to Dennis, whose [Julia answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91558/36398) made me realize I wasn't treating input `0` correctly.*

```
@(n)sprintf('%i',0:n)(n+1)<49
```

This is an anonymous function.

[Try at Ideone](http://ideone.com/c18UGf).

#### Explanation

For input `n`, this generates the Champernowne digits corresponding to the first `n+1` numbers starting at `0` (which is more than enough). `sprintf` is used for this so that no blank spaces appear. The result is true if the `n+1`-th  digit (1-based) is zero, that is, if its ASCII code is less than `49`.

Answer (score 0):

## R, 57 bytes

```
grepl("0$",substr(paste(0:(n=scan()),collapse=""),1,n+1))
```

Build a string corresponding to `0:n`, keeps the first `n+1` characters and check if the last character is a zero.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `!`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ĖJiN
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNCU5NkppTiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTMxJmZsYWdzPSE=)
or [verify some more cases](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPUwlQzMlQTYmY29kZT0lQzQlOTZKaU4mZm9vdGVyPSU3RCZpbnB1dD01MDAmZmxhZ3M9Y04=)

##### Explanation

```python
ĖJiN  # Implicit input
Ė     # Push [0..input]
 J    # Join into string
  i   # Index using input
   N  # Cast to integer
      # Logical NOT
      # Implicit output
```