# Champernowne up to me

Tags: code-golf, number, kolmogorov-complexity

Inspired by [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/91432/where-are-champernownes-zeroes).

[Champernowne's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant) is an infinite decimal number that consists of "0." followed by all natural numbers concatenated together.  It begins like so: `0.123456781011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950`, etc. The digits of Chamernowne's constant are sequence [A033307](https://oeis.org/A033307) in the OEIS.

### Your Task:

Write a program or function that, when given an integer as input, outputs/returns Champernowne's constant up to the first occurance of the input.  For example, if the input is `13`, you should output `0.12345678910111213`.  If you wish, for inputs greater than 0, you may drop the leading "0." in your output.

### Input:

An integer, or a string containing only numbers.

### Output:

Champernowne's constant up to the first occurance of the input.

### Test Cases:

```
0   -> 0
1   -> 0.1 OR 1
14  -> 0.1234567891011121314 OR 1234567891011121314
91  -> 0.1234567891 OR 1234567891
12  -> 0.12 OR 12
101 -> 0.123456789101 OR 123456789101
```

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest score in bytes wins!

Comment: [Very related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66878/42545)

Comment: @ETHproductions, thanks, I hadn't seen that.  It is very closely related, but I don't think it is quite close enough to qualify as a dupe.  However, if you disagree, feel free to CV.

Comment: @ETHproductions I can't believe I'm getting to the point where I'm forgetting about questions that I actually answered. Anyway to me that seems like a dupe, so I'll close this for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

#### Code

```
LJ¹¡н«
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fx@vQzkMLL@w9tPr/f0MDQwA)

#### Explanation

```
L         # Create the range [1, 2, ..., input]
 J        # Join into a single string
  ¹¡      # Split at occurences of the input
    н     # Take the first element
     «    # Append the input to the first element and implicitly output
```

Comment: And I thought this would actually be somewhat difficult :(

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>70</s> <s>63</s> 61  bytes

*A bunch of bytes removed thanks to [@Rod](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47120/rod), and some more thanks to [@WheatWizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)*

```
lambda x:''.join(map(str,range(1,x))).split(str(x))[0]+str(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYjBCoMwEER/ZW/uYpCk9qLgl1gPKTU2opsQ92C/Po0IM7x5E3/yDdxmN7zyZvf3x8LZV1WzBs@424iHJJUsLzMadRJRc8TNy3Vj0VFP9T2zCwkEPMOoFZiSp4Lu4qNUm6mHmDwLOhSi/Ac)

Comment: you can save [13  bytes](https://tio.run/##FcVBCoMwEEDRq8zOGQySSDcKPYkKRmzaiE5CnEV6@jSF/3nxK5/AfXHPuZz22nYLeWya7gie8bIRb0kqWX6/0KjcGiLq7nh6wTWvNOmlrRYXEgh4hkkrMLWHguFvX9dmGSEmz4IOhaj8AA) using map instead list comprehension, and backticks instead str

Comment: @Rod Thanks! I've used your `map` suggestion

Comment: @WheatWizard Good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>20</s> <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
U:VXzG&Yb1X)Gh
```

Takes the input as a string. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P9QqLKLKXS0yyTBC0z3j/391QwNDdQA)

#### Explanation

```
U      % Implicitly input a string. Convert to number
:      % Range from 1 to that
V      % Convert to string. Includes spaces as separators
Xz     % Remove spaces
G      % Push input again
&Yb    % Split at that. Gives a cell array
1X)    % Get contents of the first cell
G      % Push input again
h      % Concatenate horizontally. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>82</s> <s>73</s> 55 bytes

```hs
x!b|or$zipWith(==)x b=x
x!(a:b)=a:x!b
(!(show=<<[1..]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v0IxqSa/SKUqsyA8syRDw9ZWs0IhybaCq0JRI9EqSdM20QqogivdVkNRozgjv9zWxibaUE8vVlPzf25iZp5tQVFmXolKupKlodJ/AA)

### Explanation

First we define `!`.  `x!b` truncates `b` to the first appearance of `x`.  It does this by checking if `b` starts with `x` (`or$zipWith(==)x b`) returning `x` if it does and moving one down the string otherwise.  Then we define our main function.  Our main function is a point-free function that takes the constant (`show=<<[1..]`) and truncates it to the first appearance of `x`.  This takes `x` as a string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <del>11</del> 8 bytes

```
+hcjkSQ`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/XzsjOSs7ODDh/39LQwA) or run a [Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BhcjkSQ%60&input=101&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A14%0A91%0A12%0A101&debug=0).

Simply creates the constant (`jkSQ`) and then prints the constant up to the input (`` c ... ` ``) followed by the input (`+ ...`).

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 111 bytes

```
(m=Min@SequencePosition[s=Flatten[IntegerDigits/@Range[0,#]],t=IntegerDigits@#];FromDigits@Join[s[[;;m-1]],t])&
```